# how to send Rails object to POST request as a param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, hash, parameters

I have an rails object named app, when i send it to controller by following method then i get params[:app] as array in the controller. I have already tried a lot on stack overflow but did not found  what i was looking for

```
assert_difference("Tagging.count", 3) do
      put "/candidates/#{app.id}", {id: app.id, assigned_tags: " #{tag_one.name} #{tag_two.name} #{tag_three.name} " ,  app: app.to_json }
    end
```

how can i get the app as hash in controller through params[:app] ??

Comment: Add more context, what the variable looks like when it comes through for example. Log entry for the request would be useful.

Comment: I have an object in a test file named app , i want to get that object (app) in my controller as hash , how can i send it through params ??

Comment: You can only send through strings and numbers in params, but you can structure the content into a hash - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two data structures you can build with the name attribute of a form field.

`foo[]` will put the value into an array called `foo`

`foo[bar]` will put the value into a hash called `foo`, using the key `bar`.

eg

```
  <input type="text" name="foo[]" value="bacon">
  <input type="text" name="foo[]" value="chicken">
  => params = {:foo => ["bacon", "chicken"]}

  <input type="text" name="foo[bar]" value="bacon">
  <input type="text" name="foo[baz]" value="chicken">
  => params = {:foo => {:bar => "bacon", :baz => "chicken"}}
```

These can be combined:

```
  <input type="text" name="foo[bar][]" value="bacon">
  <input type="text" name="foo[baz][]" value="chicken">
  => params = {:foo => {:bar => ["bacon"], :baz => ["chicken"]}}

  <input type="text" name="foo[][bar]" value="bacon">
  <input type="text" name="foo[][baz]" value="chicken">
  => params = {:foo => [{:bar => "bacon", :baz => "chicken"}]}
```

Comment: Nice explanation @Max

Answer (score 0):

You can't send an object through params. Normally you should send the ID of that object in params and in receiving end you should lookup in the controller.

```
user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

If you send an object as params, it'll be converted to array automatically.